# How to append a row to a gridview instead of a full refresh

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a drop down list. On changing the index of the dropdownlist , I populate a row in asp.net gridview.

Instead of refreshing the whole gridview, I would like to append the gridview with the new row whenever there is a change in the dropdown list value.

Anyone knows how it can be done ? I have my code below :

aspx :

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClient" runat="server" Text="Client :" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvMainLog" runat="server" Visible="true" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"AllowPaging="true">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                   <div id='<%# "myRow" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'> 
                                   <asp:Literal ID="ltId" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Instruction")%>'></asp:Literal>
                                 <img src="../Images/KnobRed.png" onclick='<%# "deleteRow(\"myRow" + Container.DataItemIndex+"\")" %>'/> </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

aspx.cs

```
  protected void ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvMainLog.DataSource = GetDealerSetupUtilityByClientId(1,1);
            gvMainLog.DataBind();

        }
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(rowId) {
    $("#" + rowId).remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are setup to use server side events, but you want client side updates?

Comment: i would like to use server side events only. example : on changing the item on the dropdownlist , I would like to fetch a row from the database and append that row to the current gridview.

Answer (score 1):

try this in javascript

//Add new row

```
function AddNewRecord()
        {
            var grd = document.getElementById('GridView1');
            var tbod=grd.rows[0].parentNode;
            var newRow=grd.rows[grd.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
            tbod.appendChild(newRow);
            return false;

        }
```

//delete old row

```
function delrow(rowindex)

{

var gridID=document.getElementById("<%=grid.ClientID %>");

gridID.deleteRow(rowindex+1);     

return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably needs to be a comments but I want to show a line of code

`Container.DataItemIndex` should be replaced with `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")%>` and the function deleteRow need to come out.

Your onclick should look like this

```
onclick="deleteRow(myRow + <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")%>"
```

Comment: could you tell me what you mean by deleteRow need to come out ??

Comment: @SqlSamurai it needs to be out of "<%# %>" as written above. In your code you have written it inside onclick='<%# "deleteRow. Right way  is onclick="deleteRow(myRow + <%#Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")%>"

Comment: Hey Thank you ! My current code I posted in the question works perfectly fine. I wanted to know what I can do to append another row to the gridview instead of doing a full refresh to the page.